# How to hide the image when fixed nav appears

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/

When you scroll a bit on the site a fixed nav will appear but on this fixed navigation I want to hide the logo nav BUT I still want it to appear on the regular nav bar on the top.

[image]

Here's the CSS I am using:

```
.nav>li>a>img {
    max-width: none;
}
.menu-item a img {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

I want it to hide on a black fixed nav but I still want it to appear on the regular nav. ANy idea how to do so?

You can use the inspector of Chrome to check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nav menu has class `.affix` when it is fixed/black, so using that as the parent selector to hide the image should hide it in the fixed state without affecting the menu's default state.

```
.main-menu.affix .menu-image {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't use chrome as I am on iPad, as the navy bar looks different at the top and when it's further down the page, I'm guessing that at some point you apply a different class to the nav div?

You can target the img within that class with the style display: none;

Hope this helps, if not I'm sure some one on a computer can give more of an example